# i got error about java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONarray

Tags: java, android, mysql

In my code, I am trying to populate value spinner from a MySQL database, but I can't get the value.

What's wrong on my jsonArray?

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonSpinnerObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(fetch_city_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject city = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("onResponseSpinner", city.getString("kd_kelas") + " " + city.getString("kelas"));
                    kelasList.add(city.getString("kelas"));
                }
                spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR in response"+error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: paste the json you are receiving

Answer (score 0):

Here you set a JSON object to null then try to get JSON Array from it:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
```

I think you are wanting something like this:

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray = jsonArray = new jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject city = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("onResponseSpinner", city.getString("kd_kelas") + " " + city.getString("kelas"));
            kelasList.add(city.getString("kelas"));
        }
        spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: it's doesnt work, the error is still the same as the last cant convert JSONarray

Comment: what kind json respon, like on my comments are below ??

Comment: No, json is the response you get from the URL.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please notice onResponse you are expecting JSONObject now.

Comment: my onResponse jsonObject like my last comment its right ??

Comment: when i write this cone "JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);" there some error on "response" 
contained within the brackets

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, i think you are already getting the JSON array in response so just get the values from this JSON array only, please go through the following code

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonSpinnerObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(fetch_city_url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject city = response.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("onResponseSpinner", city.getString("kd_kelas") + " " + city.getString("kelas"));
                kelasList.add(city.getString("kelas"));
            }
            spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR in response"+error.getMessage());
    }
});
```